# Add Authentication Jwt Token

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jwt

I am using JWT for first time. Sorry for a bit silly question.
This method below generate correctly token, but this token is not addding to the Headers as authenticate. Could anyone tell me what I do wrong? When I manually added authenticate token in Postman it works correctly. My question is why `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken));`

 does not add authenticate Bearer  automatically.

```
 public User Authenticate(User user)
    {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Id.ToString()) }),
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_settings.SecurityKey)), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };
        var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken));
        }

        return new User { Id = user.Id, Name = user.Name, Password = "", Email = user.Email };
    }
```

My Startup.cs file.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("Settings");
        var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<Settings>();
        services.Configure<Settings>(appSettingsSection);

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.SecurityKey)),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
            };
        });

        services.AddDbContext<BlogContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("BlogDb"));
        services.AddScoped<UserService>();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? What is the HttpClient used for ? Should the method  Authenticate be returning jwt?

Comment: @Zulander I am using HttpClient, because I want to setting Authenticate Bearer <MyJwtToken>. Like I done it in Postman manually (screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/nX9sgH9). Should the method Authenticate be returning jwt? Why? Is not be enough. I just want to setting token in Header Authenticate. I do not want to return it unless I'm doing it wrong, then let me know. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to use JWT as an authentication method to the App... You don't need HttpClient, check out:
https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login i think it will help you !

Comment: @Zulander It explained a few things for me. Thank you.